# Highlighting and getting reference to a row in datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm new to `WPF`. I have a UI screen on which I am binding and showing a `Datagrid` in the `load_event`.
When users clicks on a row, I need to highlight it with blue color and then get a handler to the selected row.

How can I achieve this? Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and easy way is to bind your data (datasource) to your DataGrid (UI).
So, you need bind the SelectedItem property to your C# code to receive all data selected.

Sample:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfEmployees}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Grid>
```

In the following C# code, the property SelectedEmployee will contains the Employee object selected by user (WPF set automatically the row in blue).

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new PageContext();
    }
}

public class PageContext
{
    private Employee _selectedEmployee;

    public PageContext()
    {
        this.ListOfEmployees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
        this.ListOfEmployees.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Voituron", Phone = "123.456.789" });
        this.ListOfEmployees.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Dubois", Phone = "147.258.369" });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Employee> ListOfEmployees { get; set; }

    public Employee SelectedEmployee
    {
        get { return _selectedEmployee; }
        set
        {
            _selectedEmployee = value;
            Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Find more on my [blog](http://bit.ly/1GrrJBQ) (note: this article is in french)

Comment: Find [here my blog automatically translated in english](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=fr&sl=fr&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fdvoituron.wordpress.com%2F2010%2F06%2F07%2Fbinding-hierarchique-bidirectionnel-avec-notification%2F) (by Google).